# How FTP Server is Secure?

Tags: ftp, file-security

I am quite new in learning Networking and stuff related to Servers.
I have a question about FTP server security. Please forgive me if it is too simple.
I have signed up for FTP server and I uploaded a file. The URL of the file is 
zanubvideos.ezyro.com/Shortest.mp4. And anyone, who have this URL can access my file anytime anywhere. And I think this has made my file insecure, Isn't it? Then how can we say that FTP is secure?
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: There are secure protocols like SFTP and FTPS, and FTP can configure to deny anonymous access too

Comment: But I need my files to be accessed by people who use my app. For your information, my app is supposed to access the files which I upload in FTP server and show it to the user. But the problem is that those files can be accessed by anyone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a programming question. See [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

install a Secure FTP Server on Windows using IIS. or 
you can make FTP secure by using following methods :

1.Disable Anonymous Access
 2.Enable Logging
 3. Harden your ACLS.
 4. Setup your FTP site as Blind Put
 5.Enable Disk Quotas.
 6.Use Logon Time Restrictions
 7.Restrict Access by IP
 8.Audit Logon Events
 9.Enable Strong Password Requirement
10.Enable Account Lockout and Account Lockout Threshold
 for more details visit [Steps to a Secure FTP Server](http://techgenix.com/secure_ftp_server/)

Comment: But I need my files to be accessed by people who use my app. For your information, my app is supposed to access the files which I upload in FTP server and show it to the user. But the problem is that those files can be accessed by anyone. Will your solution also help me in this situation?

Comment: yup ..refer given link